# Android gradle experimental incompatible in Android Studio 2.1 preview 1

Tags: android, gradle

I've updated Android Studio to 2.1 preview 1 and i can't run projects with JNI using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203152

Updating to *com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha1* seems to work okay.

Comment: It works, But i think Android Studio should be improved to fix it.

Comment: Doesn't fix it for me. Android Studio is a piece of crap. Every update breaks something and most known issues are still unresolved. I'm fed up with this.

Comment: Got a hint on the solution from this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/aAtRYYwS5rI


dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4'
}

alphaX must match each preview update...